# React Highcharts include plugins

Tags: node.js, reactjs, highcharts

I have installed react-highcharts (npm) in order to use Highcharts into my project. Everything works fine, except the import of plugins.

When I import [highcharts-regression](https://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/22/Highcharts%20regression) for example, the console gives a

> ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined.

```
import ReactHighcharts from 'react-highcharts';
import './static/highcharts-regression.js';
```

That doesn't seem to be very hard to solve, so I tried to do the same as they do in their documentation:

```
require('./static/highcharts-regression.js')(ReactHighcharts.Highcharts);
```

However, this doesn't solve the problem. Is there another way to include this plugin when using `react-highcharts, webpack, and Babel?`

Comment: It seems that the "highcharts-regression" library is not written in React, can you follow examples from "react-highcharts". Importing another normal JS file may not work in this case

Comment: I think the plugin is just pure JS, so I don't really know if this influences React?

Answer (score 0):

you can use regression like

```
   import HC_Regression from "highcharts-regression"
   HC_Regression(Highcharts);
```

for that you need to install

```
npm install highcharts-regression
```

but still i am unable to display regression line, I need to figure it out